# Can you prevent spring-data from persisting fields declared in a superclass?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a domain object which extends a base class that contains several private fields (which are marked with the transient keyword).  I would like to prevent the super class fields from being persisted.  I unfortunately don't have control over the base class (it lives in a third party library).  I also have no option but using inheritance due to mechanics of the third party library.

Is there a way to tell spring-data to:

1. only persist fields declared in the subclass.
2. only persist fields that have been explicitly annotated with @Field for just that domain object?
3. ignore fields marked with the transient keyword?

I've tried using @AccessType(Type.PROPERTY) with @Override methods in the subclass for methods in the superclass that I didn't want persisted and annotated those with @Transient.  However it still appears to use field access for some of the fields in the superclass.

EDIT: I'm wondering whether a generic [Converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) could be written that reflectively finds the fields in just the subclass.  However I'm not sure how you'd configure Spring to use that converter for just a fixed collection of classes.

Comment: just mark the ignored fields with `@Transient`

Comment: I can't mark the ignored fields with @Transient because they exist on a third party class that I do not have control over.

Comment: Set the access mode of your subclass to field access by adding `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` annotation on the subclass so that it will override the access mode of the superclass incase the superclass is using property access mode.

Comment: Unfortunately AccessType.FIELD doesn't help, still seeing parent class fields being persisted.

Comment: Don't use inheritance

Comment: @JensSchauder Inheritance is the only option in this case - down to limitations of how a third party framework works.  But regardless, isn't the Spring philosophy to be non-intrusive?  In which case I don't see why inheritance shouldn't be used legitimately in other circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@barbakini thanks for your suggestion of using a Converter. I tried this method but it seemed a bit trickier than expected.

A working solution I have is making use of an AbstractMongoEventListener, which filters out unwanted fields in the onBeforeSave():

```
public class ConfigurableFieldFilteringMongoSaveEventListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Object> {

  private final Map<Class<?>, Collection<String>> allowedFieldsByClass;

  public ConfigurableFieldFilteringMongoSaveEventListener(Map<Class<?>, Collection<String>> allowedFieldsByClass) {
    this.allowedFieldsByClass = allowedFieldsByClass;
  }

  @Override
  public void onBeforeSave(BeforeSaveEvent<Object> event) {
    super.onBeforeSave(event);
    final Object domainObject = event.getSource();
    final Collection<String> allowedFields = allowedFieldsByClass.get(domainObject.getClass());
    if (allowedFields == null) {
      return;
    }

    final DBObject dbObject = event.getDBObject();
    dbObject.keySet().retainAll(allowedFields);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write and use a custom converter for your class and even you can map different field names diffirently from object to mongodb collection like that:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    private final List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<Converter<?, ?>>();

    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        converters.add(new YourCustomConverter());
        return new CustomConversions(converters);
    }
}
```

And YourCustomConverter class:

```
@WritingConverter 
public class CandidateConverter implements Converter<DBObject, YourClass> {

    @Override
    public DBObject convert(YourClass object) {
        DBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
        dbo.put("_id", object.get_id);
        dbo.put("iAmNotSomeField", object.getSomeField);
        return dbo;
    }
}
```

For subobject fields you need to create DBObject and put it in upper DBObject. Similiarly you can write a readingConverter too if you want. You can find more information [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html) in section 6.3.6

**UPDATE:**

For the suggestion I made in comment. Spring uses [MappingMongoConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/MappingMongoConverter.java) In class you can search for **convert** and **conversionService**

Comment: I did consider writing a custom converter, however I'd prefer a more generic solution to avoid having to write several converters.  I have several domain objects and they're fairly large, so would ideally prefer not having to map each and every field manually.

Comment: @JiteshVassa you can make all your domain classes extends an abstract class(which extends your 3rd party baseclass) Then you need to just write one converter for all your domain classes. Handling all this domain classes fields in a generic way is the job you need to do. Afterall spring use only one converter for ALL classes. 
One other fairly simple solution (if you cannot write or  know how to handle all fields of domain classes in a generic way) is that: write a converter like I told above call spring's default converter in this custom converter and just delete unwanted fields from DBObject

Comment: that sounds like a possible approach, however I couldn't find the default converter that spring uses - do you know what its called?

Comment: @JiteshVassa I added it to answer